# I want to make a switching button like drilldown

Tags: javascript

I wish...

step1: do check1 and coloring red if click the button.

step2: do check2 and coloring blue if click the button.

step3: do check1 and coloring red if click the button.

but alert are loopy.

step1: click1
step2: click1 click2
step3: click1 click2 click2 click1

i want

step1: click1
step2: click2
step3: click1

why this is loopy??
thankyou.

```js
function check1(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    check2(button);
  });

  button.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  button.style.color = '#ffffff';
  alert("click1")
}

function check2(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    check1(button);
  });

  button.style.backgroundColor = '#6495ED';
  button.style.color = '#ffffff';
  alert("click2")
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="check!" id="btn2" onclick="check1(this)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not removing the previous event listener before adding a new one, so multiple event listeners are used for the same `onclick` event.

This works:

```js
let doCheck1 = true;

function check(button) {
  if (doCheck1) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
    alert('click1');
  } else {
    button.style.backgroundColor = '#6495ED';
    alert('click2');
  }
  button.style.color = '#ffffff';
  doCheck1 = !doCheck1;
}
```

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="check!" id="btn2" onclick="check(this)">
```

Comment: thank you! this is it! 
I had knowledge increment.<br>I am Japanese people. The cherry blossom season is coming soon

Comment: @yoshitakaokada I'm not Japanese, but I'm been learning Japanese for 3 years. I actually chose this username before I started learning. 桜はきれいですね。

Comment: goodness! 3 years! you may ask me if you don't understand japanese grammar. :)